# How to pass to UDF entire relation?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Consider this script:

```
register udf-1.0.0-BETA.jar

A = LOAD '1.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (key1:chararray, val1:chararray);
B = LOAD '2.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (key2:chararray, val2:chararray);
joined = JOIN A by key1, B by key2;
out = FOREACH joined GENERATE com.example.UDF();
dump out;
```

Like so my UDF get only keys. If I try this:

```
out = FOREACH joined GENERATE com.example.UDF(joined);
```

I got an exception *A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar*

I can pass entire relation like this

```
out = FOREACH joined GENERATE com.example.UDF(A::key1, A::val1, B::key2, B::val2);
```

But it's to verbose. Is there a simpler method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, try the following:

```
out = FOREACH joined GENERATE com.example.UDF(*);
```

Comment: I knew it's possible! Thanx a lot.

Comment: Also, maybe you know why in the first example I get only keys but not values?

Comment: because you are not passing anything to the UDF

Comment: I think I get it. Thanx again.